# copy file from directory in directory stack to current directory

Tags: linux, bash

I often find myself wanting to copy files from one of the directories in my directory stack to another, and the best solution I've come up with is `cp $(dirs -p | tail -n 1)/somefile.txt ./somefile.txt`

Is there a better solution for this?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the directory stack directly via the `DIRSTACK` array; no command substitutions are needed.

```
cp "${DIRSTACK[-1]}/somefile.txt" .
```

---

Your original code was buggy for the same reason the output of `ls` should not be used programmatically; a directory name containing a newline character could break it. For example:

```
$ pushd $'foo\nbar'
$ dirs -p | head -1
~/bin/foo
```

Using `dirs +0` at least fixes that problem (assuming you correctly quote the command substitution as `cp "$(dirs +N)"/somefile.txt ./somefile.txt`, anyway):

```
$ dirs +0
~/bin/foo
bar
```

Answer (score -2):

After referncing the https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Directory-Stack-Builtins.html#Directory-Stack-Builtins, a slightly better solution is `cp $(dirs +N)/somefile.txt ./somefile.txt`

Comment: This is more than slightly better; it fixes a bug in the original. See my answer for an explanation.

Comment: You really had to downvote it, even though you think its a good solution?

Comment: I didn't cast the down vote.